# Submodule update fails with latest update

Tags: tortoisegit

Since I updated *TortoiseGit* to the latest *version 2.7.0.0*, the *Submodule Update* now fails and returns the following.

```
git.exe submodule update --progress --init --recursive --force --merge --remote -- "src/myproject"

usage: git submodule [--quiet] add [-b <branch>] [-f|--force] [--name <name>] [--reference <repository>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
or: git submodule [--quiet] status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
or: git submodule [--quiet] init [--] [<path>...]
or: git submodule [--quiet] deinit [-f|--force] [--] <path>...
or: git submodule [--quiet] update [--init] [--remote] [-N|--no-fetch] [-f|--force] [--checkout|--merge|--rebase] [--reference <repository>] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
or: git submodule [--quiet] summary [--cached|--files] [--summary-limit <n>] [commit] [--] [<path>...]
or: git submodule [--quiet] foreach [--recursive] <command>
or: git submodule [--quiet] sync [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (827 ms @ 9/13/2018 11:05:54 AM)
```

I do not use the command line, I use the TortoiseGit contextual menu.

I can always go in *Git Bash here* and enter the following commands, but I want to know why doing it from contextual menu is broken.

```
git submodule update --init --remote -f --recursive Src
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [MrTux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3906760/mrtux)

Following the link you posted, I ended up on that comment:

*Sven Strickroth @mrtux · 1 month ago
Owner
Have you checked that TortoiseGit uses the "right" version of Git? Maybe you have another older version installed which cannot handle the config value.*

The answer was to update my GIT version who was 2.08 to the latest 2.19. To do that, I just downloaded the [executable](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and it upgraded my GIT automatically.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference on the cli command line: In TortoiseGit you have checked the `merge` option, on Git bash you haven't. This might cause an incompatibility if you have set `checkout` or `rebase` in the Git configuration.

Maybe this is related to: https://tortoisegit.org/issue/3218